# Python call the recursive function on every element in the list

Tags: python, recursion

I am working on this recursive function called traverseDir, everything was going well until here, I don't know how to iterate over the list and call my traverseDir function on every element in the list. Thanks a lot if you can help!

```
path = sys.argv[1]

def traverseDir(path):

    allFile = 0
    someFile = 0

    if os.path.isfile(path): # base case
        print(sys.argv[0])
        allFile += 1
        if path.endswith('.some'):
            someFile += 1

    else:
        files = os.listdir(path)
        return files

        #if len(files[0]) <= 1: these 2 lines are where I can't figure out
         #   return traverseDir(item)
```

Comment: `len(files[0])` is the length of the first element in the `list files`. Is that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: You are trying to rewrite `os.walk`?

Answer (score 2):

A built in function called [`os.walk`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) already does this. However, for the sake of your question, you need to iterate over your `files` list. You will also need to pass `all_files` and `some_files` down through the recursion so they can accumulate as they go. You'll also need to return `all_files` and `some_files` (python lets you return multiple values as a tuple). You can then add the recursively returned values for `all_files` and `some_files`.

```
def traverseDir(path, all_files=0, some_files=0):
    # ... your existing code

    files = os.listdir(path)
    for f in files:
        # extend the path
        full_path = os.path.join(path, f)

        # unroll the returned values from the recursion
        rec_all_files, rec_some_files = traverseDir(full_path, all_files, some_files)
        # accumulate the values
        all_files += rec_all_files
        some_files += rec_some_files

    return all_files, some_files
```

This will call `traverseDir()` on every file listed. In turn, that recursion will call `traverseDir()` on every file it lists.

Comment: You forgot the needed `os.path.join(path, f)` for extending `path` in the recursive call.

Comment: I'm assuming that this function is meant to return the total of all the `allFile`s and `someFile`s, so there should be a little bit more to it.

Comment: @zondo updated to include returning `all_files` and `some_files`

Comment: @Soviut Thanks for helping, there's a --TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable --in my terminal now.. regarding the longest line

Comment: That's because you're probably not getting a list of files from `os.listdir()`. Check your output and apply filtering using if statements where necessary.

Comment: @Soviut I checked..     'files = os.listdir(path)' already exists in our code, it's still throwing that error...

Comment: @Yolanda I meant check to see if `files` contains a value. Currently, it's probably `None` which is why you're getting the `NoneType` error.

Comment: @Soviut thanxx it's solved...but instead of getting the total number of files I am getting a bunch of same files printed out..

Comment: @Soviut thnxxxxxx a lot!! ur right, finally figured it out

Answer (score 0):

**os.listdir**

```
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv[1]


def traverseDir(path):
    allFile = 0
    someFile = 0
    if os.path.isfile(path):
        allFile += 1
        if path.endswith('.some'):
            someFile += 1
    else:
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            agAllFile, agSomeFile = traverseDir(os.path.join(path, file))
            allFile += agAllFile
            someFile += agSomeFile
    return allFile, someFile

print traverseDir(path)
```

**os.walk**

```
import sys
import os

path = sys.argv[1]


def traverseDir(path):
    files = [file for dirFiles in os.walk(path) for file in dirFiles[2]]
    return len(files), len([file for file in files if file.endswith('.some')])

print traverseDir(path)
```

Comment: `os.listdir` only returns the basenames. You need to prepend the path to each of the file names: Replace `files` with say `map(lambda f: os.path.join(path, f), files)`

Comment: this function is meant to return the total of all the allFiles and someFiles... could you return the total here?